# 9Patch image on windows 7 x64

Tags: android, nine-patch

Does 9patch image work on windows 7 x64? 
I double click on "draw9patch.bat" on win7-x64 PC but it doesn't appear. After that, I run draw9patch.bat on a windows7-x86 PC and make a ninepatch image, then copy it to use on windows7-x64 PC. On the previews of xml editor, the 9patch background compatible to the linearlayout with some buttons on inside . But when I build the app to device (galaxy s2), I see the background image only, without any buttons.

Comment: works fine for me win7 x64, so that is not your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

about draw9patch.bat , make sure you have a java jre installed (i think jre 64bit should be fine) and available in the paths.

if that also doesn't work , you can edit such images yourself .simply follow the same way the editor works .

about the preview, it's just a preview so that you will know the purpose of the view (just like gridview and listview shows some fakes items in them) . you are supposed to add them yourself.